# Confusing "sort" syntax in perl

Tags: perl

I started learning Perl today and found [this](http://learnperl.scratchcomputing.com/tutorials/csss/) very interesting tutorial.
However, for the life of me I could not wrap my head around this code snippet.

```
print " $_: $created{$_}" for(sort({$created{$b} <=> $created{$a}} keys %created));
```

What kind of sort is this? More specifically, what are the variables `$a` and `$b`? 
I tried going through the [documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html), but can't say that it helped. Any support would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: First of, that tutorial is fairly up to date, but not very beginner-friendly. Consider using a book instead. _Learning Perl_ is great, or if you already are familiar with programming, _Beginning Perl_ by Curtis Poe.

Comment: @simbabque: thanks! but i need to write a script by tomorrow, so can't really give time to a studying from a book. :)

Comment: What's unclear about the documentation?

Comment: @melpomene: What are subroutines? What are XSUBs? More importantly, what are $a and $b?

Comment: Sorts the keys of `%created` according to the order of each key's value.

Comment: A subroutine is ... a unit of executable code. It is usually given a name so you can call it from multiple places. An XSUB is a subroutine implemented in XS (basically, it's written in C instead of Perl). `$a` and `$b` are variables.

Comment: Subroutines are also known as functions. $a, $b are keys in the %created hash. You should look for other tutorials that explain things better: https://alvinalexander.com/perl/edu/qanda/plqa00016 just relying on one source is just going to lead into frustration.

Comment: I think https://perlmaven.com/sorting-arrays-in-perl and https://perlmaven.com/how-to-sort-a-hash-in-perl and maybe https://perlmaven.com/how-to-sort-a-hash-of-hashes-by-value are relevant, and probably better written than your tutorial.

Answer (score 9):

There's a few things going on here. First I'll address the postfix loop;

```
say $_ for ('foo', 'bar', 'baz');
```

Which is semantically the same as doing this

```
for ('foo', 'bar', 'baz') { say $_ }
```

Now on to the sort. By default, Perl's `sort` sorts alphabetically

```
sort (20, 3, 100);  # RESULT: (100, 20, 3)
```

Perl provides a way to explicitly compare alphabetically (`cmp`) or numerically (`<=>`).

```
20 cmp 3;  # RESULT: -1 (means: Less)
20 <=> 3;  # RESULT:  1 (means: More)
20 <=> 20; # RESULT:  0 (means: Same)
```

So you can use these operators inside a `sort` block, but what do you put either side of the operators? This is where the special `$a` and `$b` variables come in.

```
sort { $a <=> $b } (20, 3, 100);  # RESULT: (3, 20, 100)
```

This is also why you should never manually assign values to `$a` or `$b` because if you do, `sort` will not function correctly!

So put it all together, and your sort is sorting a Hash's *keys* by their corresponding *values* numerically

```
my %hash = ( twenty => 20, three => 3, onehundred => 100 ); 

for ( sort { $hash{$a} <=> $hash{$b} } keys %hash ) {
    say "$_: %hash{$_}"
}
```

Outputs

```
three: 3
twenty: 20
onehundred: 100
```

You can also do `{ $b <=> $a }` to sort in reverse.

If this all looks arcane and confusing, it kinda is. I'd recommend using a module like [`Sort::Key`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sort::Key) for most of your sorting needs... or maybe [`Sort::Naturally`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sort::Naturally) if that's more what you're after.

Answer (score 6):

```
print " $_: $created{$_}" 
    for ( sort { created{$b} <=> $created{$a} } keys %created );
```

This uses the post-fix form of `for`. In Perl, `for` and `foreach` are the same. Both can be used with the C-style `for` syntax as well as the shorter `foreach` style syntax.

We can rewrite this loop to the following more verbose version.

```
foreach ( sort { created{$b} <=> $created{$a} } keys %created ) {
    print " $_: $created{$_}";
}
```

Next, let's look at `$_`. It's called the *topic* and is used as the default input for a lot of things in Perl if no other variable is given. In a `foreach` loop, if no iteration variable is used, every element of the list in the parenthesis ends up in `$_`. Again, this could be rewritten for clarity.

```
foreach my $elem ( sort { created{$b} <=> $created{$a} } keys %created ) {
    print " $elem: $created{$elem}";
}
```

Now let's look at the `sort`. The two variables `$a` and `$b` are global variables that are always there in Perl. They are reserved for the block that follows the `sort` statement.

```
sort { BLOCK } LIST
```

`$a` and `$b` contain two values from the list, that are being compared in the block. The block behaves like an anonymous function (called *lambda* in other languages), and there is no comma after it. Alternatively, you can put the name of a named sub there as a bareword without quotes. Again, there is no comma.

```
sub bubbly_sort { $a <=> $b }
sort bubbly_sort 3, 2, 1;
```

The `<=>` operator does numerical comparison. It compares both values and returns `-1`, `0`, or `1`.

```
sort { $b <=> $a } LIST
```

This will sort the values in the LIST numerically descending, so the highest value comes first. `$a <=> $b` would be ascending.

```
sort { created{$b} <=> $created{$a} } keys %created
```

The `keys` keyword gives you an unordered list of the keys inside the hash `%created`. The block in your `sort` compares the values behind those keys in the `%created` hash and sorts the keys descending. So you get out a list of sorted keys.

The rest of the code just prints out a key/value list of that sorted list of keys.

It's notable that the output is all on one line, because there is no newline after the `print`.

---

The condensed version you posted can be more readable than the long version I showed in this answer. But it stands and falls with proper indentation and use of parentheses.

```
print " $_: $created{$_}" 
    for sort { created{$b} <=> $created{$a} } keys %created;
```

versus

```
print " $_: $created{$_}" for(sort({$created{$b} <=> $created{$a}} keys %created));
```

versus

```
foreach ( sort { created{$b} <=> $created{$a} } keys %created ) {
    print " $_: $created{$_}";
}
```

In my opinion, the first version reads the most like an English sentence, which is good. Clean, readable code should always be the first priority of a good developer.

Comment: Note that the official syntax is `sort SUBNAME LIST`, and passing a subroutine reference isn't a documented option.

Comment: @Borodin Indeed it is. Huh. It actually takes the `sub {}` as part of the list. I think it needs some trickery to reimplement it to work this way.

Comment: I think it works if you just leave out the comma, because the `&` prototype converts a block into an anonymous sub, and it just doesn't get upset if you do the work for it :) I can't test right now.

Comment: A couple of nitpicks: (1) perhaps comment that the topicalizer gets _aliased_ to elements (and not that an element "ends up in `$_`")? It's a good occasion to inform people so they don't get surprised later (2) I think I see what you mean by the name `bubbly_sort()` but the algorithm is mergesort (and it had used to be quicksort); it could be misleading?  Like I said, nitpicks (details).

Answer (score 4):

Just break it down.

This is the sort bit:

```
sort({$created{$b} <=> $created{$a}} keys %created)
```

The parenthesis aren't relevant here.

```
sort { $created{$b} <=> $created{$a} } keys %created
```

So this is a very standard sort.

`sort` is [sort](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html).

The first argument is a block…

> If SUBNAME is specified, it gives the name of a subroutine that returns an integer less than, equal to, or greater than 0 , depending on how the elements of the list are to be ordered. (The <=> and cmp operators are extremely useful in such routines.) SUBNAME may be a scalar variable name (unsubscripted), in which case the value provides the name of (or a reference to) the actual subroutine to use. In place of a SUBNAME, you can provide a BLOCK as an anonymous, in-line sort subroutine.

The second argument is the thing being sorted (`keys %created`). i.e. a list of the [keys](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/keys.html) in the hash.

In the sub, `$a` and `$b` are the elements being sorted. So `$created{$b} <=> $created{$a}` takes the keys and compares the values associated with them in the hash.

So the sort outputs a list of keys in the hash, sorted by the values associated with them.

That then gets passed to a postfix `for`, so for each of the keys it does something (in the order of the values).

The something is `print " $_: $created{$_}"`: So it prints the key, then a colon, then the value.